# Can i use a jks as keystore for googleplay

Tags: android, cordova, android-theme, android-keystore, sony-xperia

I have some apps (cordova) on google play and I have used `.keystore` file 
So last week I started using Sony theme creator to build some themes for Sony xperia. But the software uses a jks key to release the theme.

So my question is: does Google play support a `mykey.jks` or just `mykey.keystore` file?

I'll use two keys  for upload the apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, Google play support the .jks file
for detail [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)